# Добавить несколько элементов в один блок

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Есть следующая структура:

```
<div class='title'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>

<div class='title'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>

<div class='title'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
<div class='list'></div>
```

Количество элементов list в каждом из "блоков" разное и количество "блоков" может быть тоже разное.
Так вот как с помощью jQuery сделать вот так:

```
<div class='block'>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
</div>

<div class='block'>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
</div>

<div class='block'>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А это всё вложенные друг в друга блоки? Покажите, где они закрываются.

Comment: ой, прошу прощения, сейчас поправлю)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бежим циклом по всем этим дивам, как увидели title, создаем новый врапер и в него переносим все дивы пока не встретится следующий title.

http://jsfiddle.net/RR9M7/1/

Answer (score 2):

Вот [еще одна альтернативка](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VzjZu/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var a,b = 0;
$('#parent div').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('title')){
        b = $(this).index();
        $('#parent div').slice(a, b).wrap('<div class="block"></div>');
        a = b;
    }
});
```

на скорую руку конечно. но идея в том что бы перебрать построчно весь блок. Но я бы посоветовал  решать такие проблемы на сервере.

Comment: не работает. index на каждой итерации пересчитывается, учитывает враперы. врапится каждый div. последняя группа не учитывается.